# write a differential equation $(\frac{dy}{dt} = ay+b)$ whose solutions have the required behavior as $ t\to\infty $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let all other solutions diverge from $y = \frac{3}{4}$. write a differential equation $(\frac{dy}{dt} = ay +b)$ whose solutions have the required behavior as t goes to infinity. Explain how you came up with the differential equation).

I think the answer is $y' = 4y - 3$ but I am not sure. Can someone help me produce the answer with complete working?

Answer (score 0):

well i think you are really close to the solution:

$$y'=-4y-3$$

Homogeneous part would be:
$$y'+ 4y = 0$$
which leads to:
$$y0=Ce^{-4t}$$

particular part would be (with initial assumption $yp=ax+b$):
$$yp=3/4$$

which leads to:
$$y(t)=Ce^{-4t}+3/4$$

$$\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} y(t)=3/4$$

Comment: Is it y' = -4y - 3 or y' = 4y - 3

Comment: y'= -4y-3 try to solve some similar equations.

Comment: @Anonymous mark the answer plz, if it was your solution

Answer (score 0):

Differential equation $y' = ax +b = f(y)$ is a nonautonuous equation. If a = 0, this equation becomes $y' = b$. Otherwise, if $a \ne 0$, the equation has a unique equibrium point $y^*  = -b/a$ and $f'(y^*) = a$. Therefore, by Lyapunov indirect method, we conclude that

If $a > 0$ then $y^*$ is unstable.

If $a < 0$ then $y^*$ is globally asymptotically stable. It implies that all solutions converge to $y^*$ as $t \to \infty$.